# How do you disable the event ctrl and click with jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a table that uses the **jquery-ui.min.js** and **the jquery.treeTable.js**.
But every time if I press on *ctrl* and somewhere on the table, the cell will be selected (a blue border will appear), 
this doesn't suppose to happen.

Does someone know how do you set this event off?

kind regards

Comment: *"this doesn't suppose to happen"* I expect it ***is*** meant to happen, that's a common way to add to an existing selection. If you want the tree control to not do that, you'll have to find something in its documentation. If there's nothing in its documentation, you may have to edit the code. There's no shortcut here (well, no reasonable one).

Answer (score 0):

I've not used jquery.treeTable.js before but from what I can see on [this demo page](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/) a css style "selected" is added to an item when it is clicked. It's a bit of a hack but you may be able to override the css style and remove the blue border.

Also they only seem to be selectable when drag-and-drop is enabled. Maybe try disabling drag-and-drop, if appropriate.

Hope that helps.